# Load Testing Without Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

Is it possible to get the load testing features of VS 2010 Ultimate without buying ultimate? Does MS sell the feature packs a la carte? I'm having a hard time finding a clear answer to this, so hopefully someone here can clarify.

Barring that, but still within the bounds of my question...are there 3rd party load testing tools that are similar to what VS 2010 Ultimate provides?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of load testing tools available - search for 'load testing software'. I'll pimp our free version: [Load Tester LITE](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html).

Comment: discontinued product, dead link